# Prevent 'git checkout' if uncommitted changes

Tags: git

I frequently have a bad time because I checkout a branch with uncommitted changes that I should have committed before changing branches but forgot.  Is there a way using some git config I can have the `git checkout` fail if there are any pending changes or new files?  I've recently gotten into the habit of running `git status` before `git checkout`, but that's inconvenient and still prone to forgetfulness.  I can probably use a Bash alias to chain those two commands together in some way, but I'm hoping there's either something I can throw in my `.gitconfig` or a flag that I'm not seeing in `git config`'s man page.

Answer (score 7):

`git checkout` will not run if the checkout would cause any changes to get lost during its process. So even if you use `git checkout` with a dirty working directory, all your changes are carried over to the other branch. And you can also just switch back to the previous branch to get in the old state.

If the branches are incompatible (for example a file you modified was deleted), `git checkout` should automatically fail, preventing you from losing any changes.

Comment: My issue is that the changes are usually compatible, so I don't notice, do a `git commit -am msg` after hacking on the other branch, and then have to back the changes out of that other branch and patch them back into the original.  99% of the time, I'd rather just have `checkout` fail than let me do this.

Comment: I couldn't agree more, @Michael. This "feature" is totally backwards. I just plain *don't want* any modified files to be automagically carried over. I'd rather it just fail. The `git stash` command should be used to carry files over, not leave them behind. Perhaps `git smuggle` would be better nomenclature.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use

git stash

to save your uncomitted changes on a stack.

git stash list (to see which stashed you have stored)

git stash apply (to apply your changes stored in stash)
You can even create branch from the stash.  Refer gitscm book for more information (http://git-scm.com/book)

Comment: Note that this answer doesn't answer his question, which is "how can I make sure I don't lose data if I accidentally checkout". poke's answer got it right already, though.